# Preventing mid-word line breaks in a2ps

Tags: shell-script, printing, text, postscript, a2ps

So I understand that `a2ps` is mostly for converting ASCII code to postscript for printing, but occasionally I like to print a .txt or .md file for school. Often, an entire sentence (or even a paragraph) will be on one line, and `a2ps` will break the line at whatever character it needs to in order to wrap correctly.

This often leaves either awkward half words on a line, or spaces immediately at the beginning of the line. I can't seem to find an option to prevent this hard wrapping in the middle of words (even with `--pretty-print`).

Is there any option to do this, or am I using the incorrect tool for the task?

Comment: Can you include a sample .txt file that exhibits this behavior? Just a fragment would be sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my past experiences with `a2ps`, it doesn't handle wrapping in an intelligent manner. So you have to present your text file already formatted to the proper width & wrapping, before handing it off to `a2ps`.

If your system has `enscript` installed I'd make use of that instead. Googleing for "word wrap a2ps" will lead you to this article titled: [Printing Plain Text](http://machine-cycle.blogspot.com/2007/09/printing-plain-text.html), which includes the following `enscript` example:

```
$ enscript --header='||Page $% of $=' \
    --margin=72:72:72:72 -1 \
    --word-wrap \
    --media=A4 file.txt
```

**NOTE:** (one inch margins on all sides, 1 up, word wrap, A4 page size, right aligned header showing page info).

Check out the `enscript --help` and man pages for more on the options, or google for additional examples. I've used `enscript` for years for printing various text files and source code and it "just works", once you get the switching the way you like.

Comment: Thanks! Enscript works great — I'll have to dig through the man page to find how to add headers, etc, but the breaking is much smarter than in a2ps. Shame-I really like a2ps. Thanks again!

Comment: ditto -- thanks, enscript works great, and solves my a2ps line-wrap problems

Answer (score 2):

I have struggled with this as well but have found an answer that works for me.

It's a two-step process:

```
fmt inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
a2ps outputfile.txt
```

Of course that can happen all on one line:

```
fmt inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt; a2ps outputfile.txt
```

And if you like you can also `rm` the `outputfile.txt`.

I've done this several times now and the formatting works just great in default modes.